# Understand the summary of a LSTM model

Tags: python, deep-learning, lstm

I have the following LSTM model. Can somebody helps me understand the summary of the model?

a) How the param# are calculated?

b) We have no value?

c) the param# near the dropoout why is 0?

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(64, return_sequences=True, recurrent_regularizer=l2(0.0015), input_shape=(timestamps, 
input_dim)))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(LSTM(64, recurrent_regularizer=l2(0.0015), input_shape=(timesteps,input_dim)))


model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))

model.add(Dense(n_classes, activation='softmax'))
model.summary()
```

The following are the input, timestamps, and x_train

```
timesteps=100
input_dim= 6
X_train=1120
```

The summary is:

```
    Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
    lstm_1 (LSTM)                (None, 100, 64)           18176     
_________________________________________________________________
    dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 100, 64)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
    lstm_2 (LSTM)                (None, 64)                33024     
_________________________________________________________________
    dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 64)                4160      
_________________________________________________________________
    dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 64)                4160      
_________________________________________________________________
    dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 6)                 390       
=================================================================
    Total params: 59,910
    Trainable params: 59,910
    Non-trainable params: 0
```

Comment: What do you not understand specifically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of your question is answered here.

https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/10615/number-of-parameters-in-an-lstm-model

Simply put, the reason there are so many parameters for an LSTM model is because you have tons of data in your model and many weights need to be trained to fit the model.

Dropout layers don't have parameters because there are no weights in a dropout layer. All a dropout layer does is give a % chance that a neuron won't be included during testing. In this case, you've chosen 50%. Beyond that, there is nothing to configure in a dropout layer.

Comment: thank you. so the first lstm layer has 4 x (64x6 +64x64 + 64)==18176. i do not understand the param of the next lstm but I will find it.

Answer (score 0):

1. How parameters are calculated?

well!!. the input dimension is 6 and the hidden neurons in the first LSTM layer is 64.

so the first LSTM layer takes input [64 (initialized hidden state) + 6 (input)] in this form. so we can say the input dimension is 70 [64 (hidden state at t-1) + 6 current input at t].

Now the calculation part.

no of parms  = input dimension * hidden units + bias.

```
         = [64 (randomly initialized hidden state dimension) + 6 (input dimension)]*64( hidden neurons ) + 64 ( bias 1 for each hidden neurons)

         = (64+6)*64+64
```

for one FFNN = 4544

But LSTM has 4 FFNN, so simply multiply it by 4.

Total trainable params = 4 * 4544

```
                   = 18176
```

3. Dropout layer does not have any parameters.
4. I am not sure which value you are talking about.?